# switch browser tab from another tab with out reload tab using javascript..

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mozilla

switch browser tab from another tab with out reload (Already opened tabs) using JavaScript. It is working in chrome by giving target name in window.open but not working in Firefox and IE 11.

Comment: I am looking for so long but I can't find a single line of code here

Comment: call `window.focus()` on the blurred tab to bring it in focus

Comment: @dandavis i tried but it is not working.